# Stata randomly produces "program error: code follows on the same line as close brace" only sometimes

Tags: stata, braces

I have some Stata code that **sometimes** produces the error:

```
program error:  code follows on the same line as close brace.
```

Other times it runs.

What is strange is that the code will run, maybe 80% of the time, but then sometimes it hits this error. If I try it again later or run the same code I have copied in a different folder, it will run again.

The problem could be with the big `foreach` loop I have, as it crashes around there.

Sometimes it will get through looping a few of the elements (in my case sheets) mentioned there before crashing, but the issue is not with one specific element of the loop, because it will crash at different ones, when it does crash.

The code accepts country names as a user-input, but even for the same country name, sometimes it runs and sometimes I get the error. So the error is *not* generated by any specific country in the data causing problems vs others.

I am also open to other suggestions to getting the same results as my code in a different way that avoids the error.

The other strange thing is that before I integrated some python code into Stata, I don't recall ever getting the error. But now the code crashes before it reaches the python code.

Here the relevant blocks of code (not the most elegant):

```
quietly {

* Stata Paths
global path_import "`c(pwd)'"
global path_export "`c(pwd)'/Results"
*********************************************************************************************
* Get country input from user
    noisily di in red "Enter the country" _request(ans)
    global Country "$ans"
*********************************************************************************************
* Analysis - THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR COMES IN 

    foreach x in "Biggest Obstacle" "Corruption" "Crime" "Finance" "Firm Characteristics" "Gender" "Informality" "Infrastructure" "Innovation and Technology" "Performance" "Regulations and Taxes" "Trade" "Workforce" {
        
    import excel "$path_import/$datafilename" , sheet("`x'") firstrow clear
    
    keep if Economy=="$Country" 
    *some basic cleaning after this, just droping and relabling/renaming variables with no braces and no loops
        
    export excel "$path_export/indicator_sector.xlsx" , sheet("`x'" , replace) firstrow(varlabels)
    }

python
#basic python code
end 

}
```

Comment: There's probably a characteristic of one of the Excel files or sheets that is different to the other sheets. You could try using -set trace on- to identify exactly where your code is encountering the error. If you're running the same code on the same input files each time, the error should occur every time. Also, it is generally advised to use local macros, rather than global macros, unless you have a compelling reason to use global macros (since global macros persist between run cycles, which can create unexpected behaviours).

Comment: Thanks I’ll give it a try. It’s only one excel file and the code loops thorough all sheets of that one file. I am indeed running the same code on the same input each time and the error randomly appears sometimes but not other times, which makes no sense and is driving me crazy.

Comment: It's worth checking if there is something different about one of the sheet names. Is it possible for Excel sheet names to contain a carriage return?

Comment: Something is going on here that has an explanation.  Stata's parser like any other I know about can guess wrong. Unfortunately I don't think the evidence here allows either replication or anything beyond helpful hints such as those from @Bicep. Voting to close.

Comment: @NickCox thanks very much for your hints. If you cannot help me then I am truly lost. Happy for any other hints. For example, is there a creative way to loop through excel tabs that avoids the potential parser issues (guesses) you mention?

Comment: Sorry, but I am no kind of Excel expert. I can't even follow what you are trying to do, as each time you read in a different country it seems that you export it to the same Excel worksheet. -- so overwriting all previous work???

Comment: @NickCox, sorry for the confusion. I am simply importing all the excel tabs in a file. Then I do some basic cleaning for each tab. Then export to a new single excel file with different tabs, but with the  same nr of tabs and with the same name of tabs as the original file. So the output excel files looks the same as the input excel file, except the data is “processed”/cleaned.

Comment: So the strings in the loop are just the names of the excel tabs. I have also tried more elegantly to just save the names of the tabs in a local using import excel, describe and then loop over those. Then there’s no need for me to specify the excel tab names. But I get the same issue.

Comment: Well, as the code makes no sense to me it (sadly) follows that I can't help here.  Otherwise put, each time your code asks for a country you write results to sheet `x` -- regardless of the country. That's how I read it. Perhaps the code you don't show us explains. But that's part of the problem. You don't have a self-contained reproducible problem -- and I can't suggest how to write one. As the code is the same we are left with the guess of @Bicep that you need to look again at the sheet names.

Comment: If anyone can solve this, they do deserve the bounty!

Comment: @NickCox: " each time your code asks for a country you write results to sheet x -- regardless of the country." That is true, basically, I only want to run it for one country at a time, for unrelated reasons. I have an excel file with multiple sheets and each sheet contains many countries. Say I want to import each sheet of the file, keep the one specified country in each sheet, then export all sheets to another excel file. Simple enough in theory and the code runs 80% of the time. But indeed something in the sheet names must be tripping up Stata. Anyway, thanks for your time!